# CSS live editing - Play framework

Tags: css, playframework, livecoding

i have made a webpage and now it is "feature-complete".
As a next step i want to put some style to it.

The project is based on the Play framework and i choose SCSS as my CSS alternative (with an SBT plugin to convert SCSS -> CSS).

Every time i change some CSS i have to reload the page in the browser, which takes a while, see if i like it and keep or revert. Then start over.

This workflow does not seem right to me. How do you style a webpage built with Play (specifically: i use Play templates, so i cannot just copy every piece of HTML into a CSS editor and style everything from there)?

The best way that i found is to change the CSS directly in Chrome, remember the changes and apply them to the source file later on.

Is there a more "automatic" way of doing things? Any nice editors or browser plugins that change the source file directly? What am i missing?
What are other people, using Play framework (or other templating systems) doing?

Thank you!

Comment: I've had great success with variations of https://github.com/livereload/LiveReload. There are many different ways to integrate it into your workflow, depending on the tools you use.

Comment: Also note that you can add your workspace to chrome, which means when you're editing a style in the browser, it will automatically edit the source file as well. However this only works with plain CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can download an extension that automatically refresh's your page every ... seconds. On this way you only have to "Alt-tab" between your code and your page. 
BTW: I couldn't comment this, I need 50 reputation. Otherwise I wouldn't have commented it because this isn't really an answer but this is just my advice.

Comment: I already have such a plugin installed. It reloads the page when i change smth in my editor. The problem is: The plugin reloads the whole page...and pages are quite heavy. I want a plugin that just reloads/injects the new CSS in the rendered page without a reload. That should be significantly faster.

Comment: Oh okay. well I dont know anything for that sorry. @Lazarus535